# How to read file name using php?

Tags: php

I have three .txt files. Every file has a different name. Example:-

01_ABC.txt will be import to ABC table.

02_DEF.txt will be import to DEF table.

03_GHI.txt will be import to GHI table.

my problem is, how can I import the data from the text file into table based on file name?

Comment: Did Google did not work? https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php would help

Answer (score 0):

```
$name = basename($path,".txt");
```

then you select the table based on $name

Answer (score 0):

Use `glob()` to get all *.txt files in a directory. After loop through every file with a `foreach` loop and get the content of each file using `file_get_contents`() and put the content into the target file with `file_put_contents()`

```
<?php

    $files = glob("path/*.txt");
    $output = "output.txt";

    foreach($files as $file) {
        $content = file_get_contents($file);
        file_put_contents($output, $content, FILE_APPEND);
    }

?>
```